# Subtract from current date if second date field is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a script that will substract by todays date for all rows where the second date field is empty. I've tried using 'IsDate(SecondDate)= False' instead of SecondDate= "", but that didn't work either. That field is empty, but the script isn't recognize it as empty and I dont know how to call it in the script.

```
Dim dtToday, FirstDate, SecondDate As Date
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")
Dim Column1 As Long, Column2 As Long, Column3 As Long, RowNo As Long
dtToday = Date

RowNo = 2
Column1 = 1
Column2 = 2
Column3 = 3
Column4 = 4

For RowNo = 2 To 10000
    FirstDate = ws.Cells(RowNo, Column1)
    SecondDate = ws.Cells(RowNo, Column2)
    If IsDate(FirstDate) And SecondDate= "" Then
        ws.Cells(RowNo, Column4).Value = DateDiff("d", FirstDate, dtToday)
    End If
Next
```

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

Comment: `SecondDate= 0`

Comment: BTW `Dim dtToday, FirstDate, SecondDate As Date` only `SecondDate` is declared as a `Date` the others are `Variant`  you want `Dim dtToday As Date, FirstDate As Date, SecondDate As Date`

Comment: SIde note, this could, also be done with a formula: `=IF(ISBLANK(B2),TODAY(),B2)-A2`

Comment: or you could just do `SecondDate = IIF(ws.Cells(RowNo, Column2)="",date(),ws.Cells(RowNo, Column2))` then only deal with `SecondDate`